# Sorting data by three separate columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort data in a spreadsheet by three different values:

1. Column F - Values - Oldest to Newest
2. Column B - Values - Smallest to Largest
3. Column A - Values - Z to A

The code stops with an error on the ***.Apply*** section. I fear the cell selection is the issue.

```
Sub DatePartOrderSort()
'
' DatePartOrderSort Macro
'
'
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range(Cells(5, "A"), Cells(LR, "J")).Select
    '
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Date Order").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Date Order").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    Cells(5, "A"), Cells(LR, "J")), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Date Order").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    Cells(5, "A"), Cells(LR, "J")), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Date Order").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    Cells(5, "A"), Cells(LR, "J")), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Date Order").Sort
        .SetRange Range(Cells(5, "A"), Cells(LR, "J"))
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub DatePartOrderSort()
'
' DatePartOrderSort Macro
'
'
    LR = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range(Cells(5, "A"), Cells(LR, "J")).Select
    '
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Date Order").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Date Order").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "F5:F" & LR), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Date Order").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "B5:B" & LR), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Date Order").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "A5:A" & LR), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Date Order").Sort
        .SetRange Range(Cells(5, "A"), Cells(LR, "J"))
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks you for this - I now have lots of blank rows and I want to leave the last two blank is there anyway of using VBA to do this.

Comment: put this into a new question.